# Java: How to convert from Vector to Arraylist

Tags: java, collections

I want to convert a code written with `Vector` collection interface to convert to `ArrayList` . Can someone suggest on this

Comment: What's the question, exactly? Why can't you just do it?

Answer (score 6):

`Vector` implements `List`, so it should be the same - simply replace `Vector` with `List:`List`list = new Vector<Foo>()`. (Note that `Vector` is not an interface - it's a class)

If you have used the vector-specific methods, like `addElement`, change them:

- `addElement(..)` > `add(..)`
- `elementAt(..)` > `get(..)`
- `removeElement(At)(..)` > `remove(..)`

If you need the synchronization of the vector, you can then use `Collections.synchronizedList(list)`

If you want to keep the vector, but get rid of the unnecessary synchronization - use `List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>(vector)`

And if you want to get better answer, state your questions more precisely ;)

Comment: Vector data = new Vector(4);
    data.addElement(dataObject.getProfile());
    data.addElement(dataObject.getOwnerBusId());
    data.addElement(dataObject.getOwnerRegType());
    data.addElement(dataObject.getDescription()); I want to convert this code in arraylist only . Please suggest me on this .

Comment: Change `addElement` to simply `add`, as I wrote

Answer (score 3):

You can just assign your vector to a new ArrayList.

`List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>(vector);`